# how to read previous and next line if the current line is valid for an IF statement in Python

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, input

I am reading a gzipped file in this way

```
import sys;
import gzip;
import csv;

def iscomment(s):            ##function to get rid of the header of the file which every line starts with #
    return s.startswith('#')

with gzip.open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in dropwhile(iscomment, f):
        for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"):
            if (int(line[1]) in myHdictionary):
                print PreviousLine,"\n",line,"\n",NextLine,"\n"
            else:
                continue
```

Therefore, if the current line meets the IF statement, I would like to retrieve the previous and next line of the current line of the file.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!
thanks in advance!

Comment: Always read 3 lines and if the middle one passes the test, you already have the other two, if not, Read the next lines.

Comment: You need to put the `dropwhile()` around the `csv.reader()` here; what you are doing *happens* to work but you are skipping one line too many. You'll have to skip *rows* where the first column starts with `#` here in that case.

Comment: And for having a previous and next line: keep *two previous lines* in memory at all times. Then whenever the last of those two matches, you can print the first of the two previous lines and the current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to look forward when backwards will do:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice, dropwhile
import csv

def iscomment(row): return row[0][0] == '#'

with gzip.open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    reader = dropwhile(iscomment, csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"))
    history = deque(islice(reader, 2), maxlen=2)

    for row in reader:      
        if history[-1][1] in myHdictionary:
            print history[0]
            print history[-1]
            print row
        history.append(row)
```

You need to wrap the `csv.reader()` *itself* in the `dropwhile()` iterator (with an adjusted condition); otherwise you'll be skipping a line at the start that the `csv` reader will never see.

The `deque` object holds 2 previous lines at all times, letting you peek at those lines as you go through the CSV file. `history[-1]` is the previous line, `history[0]` the line before that. If `history[-1]` column 1 is in `myHdictionary`, your condition is matched.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I get this error message in the line "history = deque(islice(reader, 2), maxlen=2)" IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces? Make sure the line indentation matches the previous line (defining `reader`).